# Prevent window.onbeforeunload event from being fired while clicking on hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a page where the user is prompted to confirm the unloading of the page by using the `window.onbeforeunload` event handler. This message is currently getting fired even when there is a navigation from one page to another as a result of clicking on a hyperlink (anchor tag).

How can I stop the event from being fired when the hyperlink or anchor tag is clicked? My code is provided below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

    $("form").live("submit", submitListener);
      function submitListener(e) {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
      }
  });
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit() {
    return "Your changes will be lost if not saved...";
  }
</script>

<a title="Delete Document" class="btn btn-danger" 
   onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete this Committee?');" 
   href='@Url.Action("Delete", "ManageCommittee", new { id =Model.Id})' 
   style="margin-left:5px;">
     <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>&nbsp;<span>Delete</span>
</a>


<p>I dont want alert while user click on the anchor tag</p>
```

Comment: I have reworded your title to be a bit shorter (yet have the same meaning) and also your description to better explain your needs. Your question as it is was pretty good and clear :)

Comment: Harry can you please provide me the answer..of the above question

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't be able to help with the answer because I don't have much expertise in the area. I just happened to find your question in the review queue.